# Web Scrape URLs with R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am currently attempting get the URLs of all players that have been drafted in the NFL in the past couple years.

> A sample link [here](http://www.nfl.com/draft/2015/tracker?icampaign=draft-sub_nav_bar-drafteventpage-tracker#dt-tabs:dt-by-position/dt-by-position-input:qb).

I am going to do a nested for loop of

```
yearsVector <- c("2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015")
positionVector <- c("qb", "rb", "wr", "te", "ol", "dl", "lb", "cb", "s")
for (i in 1:length(yearsVector)) {
  for (j in 1:length(positionVector)) {

  }
}
```

to get all of the players of position qb, then rb, etc. then go to the next year and continue. And this is only for the players in the drafted part, not prospects.

> I believe I have the XPath='//*[@id="players-grid-table-by-position-drafted"]'.

I have attempted to grab links and successfully grabbed them but they never grabbed the one I wanted. I don't have the code anymore but it grabbed a total of 133 or so and one for 139. I am trying to get the player links and then placing them into a vector.

I have tried other ways of web scraping URLs on this site and none of those work for the site that I am using it for.

Comment: _"you agree not to transmit, distribute, post, communicate or store information or other material on, to or through the Services that…(f) use or attempt to use any engine, software, tool, agent or other device or mechanism (including, without limitation, browsers, spiders, robots, avatars or intelligent agents) to navigate or search the Services to harvest or otherwise collect information from the Services to be used for any commercial purpose;"_ NOTE: betting pools & $-reward fantasy football == commercial uses

Comment: What did you try? Show some scraping code you've tried and we can help.